# Find the domain to make the integral max

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

Find the domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the value of the integral
$$
\iint\limits_D (1-x^2-y^2) \,\mathrm{d}A
$$
is maximum.

I only have basic definitions and properties of Darboux integral on a general domain; no Fubini yet and no change of variables.  I'm thinking to use the following facts:

- If $A \subset B$, $f$ is integrable on $A$ and $B$ with $f \ge 0$, then $\int\limits_A f \le \int\limits_B f$.
- If $f \le g$, then $\int\limits_D f \le \int\limits_D g$.

Applying to this problem, I'm going to find the maximum area of $D$ such that $1-x^2-y^2 \ge 0$.  That means $D$ must be a *disk* center $O$ and radius $1$.

Am I right?  I feel like my work is not concrete at all, not mathematically reasoning.

What should I do?  Thank you very much.

Comment: The area you're trying to find is the area of the $(x,y)$ plane where $1-x^2-y^2 \ge 0$. Because, think about it: If the area was any larger, then there would be some points where $1-x^2-y^2 < 0$, making the integral decrease. And if the area was any smaller, then integrating a positive function over a strictly smaller  area would make the result smaller as well. So yes, your intuition is correct: $D$ must be a cicle with center $O$ and radius $1$.

Comment: Hint: use $f \le max(0, f)$

Comment: Rather a *disk*.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, it should be a disk, not a circle.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the maximum value is attained for the domain $C:=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$, i.e. the disk centered at the origin of radius $1$. Indeed, if $D$ is any measurable set in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ then
$$\begin{align}
\iint_D (1-x^2-y^2) \,\mathrm{d}A&=\iint_{D\cap C} (1-x^2-y^2) \,\mathrm{d}A
+\iint_{D\setminus C} \underbrace{(1-x^2-y^2)}_{<0} \,\mathrm{d}A\\
&\leq \iint_{D\cap C} (1-x^2-y^2)\,\mathrm{d}A\\
&\leq \iint_{D\cap C} (1-x^2-y^2)\,\mathrm{d}A+\iint_{C\setminus D} \underbrace{(1-x^2-y^2)}_{\geq 0}\,\mathrm{d}A= \iint_{C} (1-x^2-y^2)\,\mathrm{d}A.
\end{align}$$
Such maximum value can be easily calculated  by using polar coordinates:
$$\iint_{C} (1-x^2-y^2)\,\mathrm{d}A=2\pi\int_{0}^1(1-\rho^2)\rho\, d\rho=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$